# Pandas Python Add Rows Based on the below condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have an integer `n=3`

I have to create a square matrix
with below condition `when matrix[row]=matrix[column] then 1 else 0`

My plan is to create a table, insert `n` number of rows with all nulls initially and write an update with the above case statement in pandas sql.

Can anyone please help on this case to create a dataframe initially with `n` rows and `n` columns dynamically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using `numpy` and `pandas`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def create_diagonal_matrix_of_size(n):
    if n > 0:
        d = np.diag(n * [1])
        df = pd.DataFrame(d)
        return df
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame()

print(create_diagonal_matrix_of_size(3))
```

Comment: Thank you I want to use only Pandas & SQL concepts if possible thank you for your answer & quick response.

Comment: Pandas uses numpy. So, if you are using Pandas, you have access to numpy already.

Comment: I am sorry for asking a dumb question, if i do it below :

for i in range(0,n,1):
...     a.append(n)
for i in range(0,len(a),1):
    c.append([a])

Can i create a Dataframe on above & write a sql update .... with Spark sql probably... I am just curios on time complexity space.....